# Subtract 6 months from date that has formula

Tags: sql, date, ssms

I have a formula that replaces a year in a datetime field, and then also casts the datetime field as a date:

```
cast(DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY,GETDATE()),LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) as date) as [New Date]
```

which returns a result like this: 2017-08-07 from: 2008-08-07. Now, I need to subtract 6 months from this, so the new result would be 2017-02-07. I made the following change, which resulted in an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

```
cast(DATEADD(Month,-6,cast(DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY,GETDATE()),LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) as date) as [6 mo Anniv]
```

Comment: you may have forgotten to add 2 more close parentheses for your new CAST and DATEADD before as [6 mo Anniv]

Comment: Why has this question been down-voted? The question shows that the OP has attempted to solve their own question?

Comment: Thank you. I did attempt that originally. Nothing underlines to highlight an error, but still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to put parentheses to close your new CAST and DATEADD functions for subtracting 6 months to the original result. Also, your new CAST function should include the AS DATE.

`CAST(DATEADD(Month,-6,cast(DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'01/01/2017',GETDATE()),'01/01/2017') AS DATE)) AS DATE) as [6 mo Anniv]`

Comment: I see what I missed. This fixed my issue. Many thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. You may check this as the answer to this inquiry to close this.